# AWS Lambda function to start/stop Aurora Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I am running an staging Aurora Cluster on AWS consisting of 1 writer and 1 reader with Engine version: 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2.

Is there a way to schedule start/stop of aurora cluster via lambda ? The idea here is to **save cost**. I was able to schedule start/stop of my EC2 instance with lambda and cloudwatch rules with a cron expression. But i cannot find anything similar for my aurora cluster.

Comment: posted a solution which references aws docs and suitable api's to achieve your task, as aws recommends you can use aws eventbridge for scheduling your lambda, if the answer helped you in any, cn you please accept/upvote so that it may help others in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

This option is available:
[Starting the cluster](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.start_db_cluster) and [Stopping the cluster](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.stop_db_cluster)

You can write lambda function like this:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

aurora_db_cluster = 'your-db-cluster-identifier'
response = client.stop_db_cluster(
    DBClusterIdentifier=aurora_db_cluster
)

response = client.stop_db_cluster(
    DBClusterIdentifier=aurora_db_cluster
)
```

Make sure lambda function has IAM rights to perform this action.

Comment: Awesome!! Good to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Docs starting and stopping Aurora cluster is possible using [StartDBCluster and StopDBCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-cluster-stop-start.html#aurora-cluster-stop) api's

The document will redirect to [API page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_StopDBCluster.html).

I am choosing an example of boto3 API which can be used with lambda.

for [starting aurora cluster.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.start_db_cluster)

```
response = client.start_db_cluster(
    DBClusterIdentifier='string'
)
```

for [stopping aurora cluster](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.stop_db_cluster)

```
response = client.stop_db_cluster(
    DBClusterIdentifier='string'
)
```

For event scheduling i would recommend to use [AWS Eventbridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) along with  Lambda.

**Note** :- you would need to Create an IAM Role and attach start stop Policy for lambda to access AWS aurora cluster